# Apply a fixed px unit for each image

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have an image that is a card i need to repeat it 30 times, and on each time i want to apply for a specific card a left position so it overlaps the card before staying on a position like a deck.

The thing is, when i apply a left position to the image card, it applies the same left position to all cards, so there is no overlap position.

**So i have something like this:**

```
<template>
  <div class="triPack">
    <img :style="{'left': -index * 30}" v-for="index in 30" :key="index" src="../../assets/images/cardThemes/blue.png" alt="">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .triPack {
    display: flex;
    img {
      width: 80px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
</style>
```

[image]

**i want something like this:**

[image]

Thank you guys.

Comment: keep them inflow with position set an simply add negative margin-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with only css  `margin-left` except the first image `:not(:first-child)`

So remove it `:style="{'left': -index * 30}"`

```css
.triPack {
   display: flex;  }
img {
   width: 80px;
   height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    }
img:not(:first-child) {
margin-left: -45px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="triPack">
    <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0gL.png" alt="">
    <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0gL.png" alt="">
    <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0gL.png" alt="">
    <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0gL.png" alt="">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: tell for more help